# Firebase Uploader AsyncTask doinBackground() error android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using chat application. Upto Android 28sdk its worked fine but after i refract to androidx am facing this problem please check my code below and error screenshot.

[Error Code Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGh5f.jpg)

[Error Code Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXADc.jpg)

```js
private void compressAndUpload(final Context context, final String child, final File file) {
        compressionTask = new AsyncTask<File, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(File... files) {
                String filePathCompressed = null;
                Uri originalFileUri = Uri.fromFile(files[0]);
                File tempFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), originalFileUri.getLastPathSegment());
                //tempFile = File.createTempFile(originalFileUri.getLastPathSegment(), null, context.getCacheDir());
                if (child.equals("images")) {
                    filePathCompressed = SiliCompressor.with(context).compress(originalFileUri.toString(), tempFile);
                } else {
                    try {
                        filePathCompressed = SiliCompressor.with(context).compressVideo(files[0].getPath(), context.getCacheDir().getPath());
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (filePathCompressed == null)
                    filePathCompressed = "";
                return filePathCompressed;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                File compressed = new File(s);
                fileUri = Uri.fromFile(compressed.length() > 0 ? compressed : file);
                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                if (uploadRef == null)
                    uploadRef = storage.getReference().child(child).child(fileUri.getLastPathSegment());

                if (replace) {
                    upload();
                } else {
                    checkIfExists();
                }
            }
        };

        compressionTask.execute(file);
    }
```

Comment: your 1st image says arithmatic exception happening inside the SiliCompressor library, check if you are passing valid image path to async task, try checking by loggin the image path in doInBackground method

Comment: Yes you are correct the problem with silicompressor when make update for silicompressor the error coming now i sorted out the issue as per their library documentation.